# Exact Online API: deleting and updating items like BankEntryLines

Tags: python, api, rest, odata, exact-online

We are building an exensive api-link with the Exact online odata API. Problem we are having is that many objects cant be updated or deleted. For instance BankEntryLines, GeneralJournalEntryLines.
We have now worked around this by creating new EntryLines upon each update or delete, but this creates much unclarity in some cases.

Can the API be changed, or can I get extra authorization to be able to update or delete these objects, just like is possible in the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

As the Exact Online REST API doesn't support modifying on quite some objects, there is no way to achieve what you want using the REST API. If the Exact Online XML API doesn't support updating either, there is only one solution left.

That solution is forbidden by Exact, and it could risk you lose you application developer status. You can make those changes using HTTP POSTS on the web site itself. If you can extract the calls that are made through the screens, you can mimic their behavior and by replaying that, you can modify what you need.

If you want to make a coupling to Exact Online and you are starting with developing, I want to suggest you to take a look at [Invantive Data Hub](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-data-hub), which allows updating Exact Online using SQL syntax. (To give full disclosure: I work for that company)

Comment: It always helps to also register a call on the topic "API/webservices" in Exact Online thru Help -> My Questions -> Register request. Explicitly note that you would like an enhancement request added and that you would like to know the number assigned. Asking generic "I want everything to be update/delete/insertable" can take long; better be specific what topics you would like to have improved with a short use case description.

Comment: Oh, please also note that for some topics you can insert, but that you must provide a detail record right away, such as with SalesOrders. No sales order without a sales order line.